# How to send selected datagrid objects with ajax in devextreme

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, devextreme

Friends, with devextreme datagrid, I cannot capture the selected objects in the asp.net core controller.
The values appear as json in chrome web tools. But I can't fill the data with ajax on the controller side.
Thanks for help

View :

```
 var datas=[];
    var gDeger;
    function selection_changed(selectedItems) {
        datas = selectedItems.selectedRowsData;
        $.map(datas,function (x) {
            gDeger = [{ Id: x.Id, Email: x.Email }];
        })
        console.log(datas); //The values appear as json in chrome web tools
        myfunction(datas);
    };

  function myfunction(gdeger) {            
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType:"json",
            url: "/Admin/SendSablon",
            data: { eBultens: JSON.stringify(gdeger) },
            success: function (message) {
                console.log("true");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendSablon(List<EBulten> eBultens) // eBultens is null =(
    { 
        return Json(true);
    }
```

Comment: did you try to replace "List<EBulten> eBultens" with "string eBultens" just to be sure the data is passed in the correct variable? If so, then there is a problem with the deserialization, if not, then there is a problem with the variable itself (maybe casing)

Comment: Now I tried. result :"[{\"Id\":2,\"Email\":\"ynsbldk@gmail.com\",\"Date\":\"2021-01-01T00:00:00\ ",\"Status\":true},{\"Id\":3,\"Email\":\"gruptria@hotmail.com\",\"Date\":\"2021-01-01T00: 00:00\",\"Status\":true}]"

Comment: I solved my problem by using jsonconvert.deserializeobject on controller side

Answer (score 0):

On the controller side, you should use this to get your values:

```
public IActionResult SendSablon(string values)
{
    dynamic keys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(values);
    var Id = keys.Id;
    var Email = keys.Email;
    // rest of code
}
```